# Processing zoom, pan and camera on processing

Tags: javascript, processing

I am looking to do the following four things to my code:

1. pan using mouse
2. zoom using mouse wheel
3. snap view by double-clicking a mouse button
4. use a mix of orthogonal and perspective camera projection

When I try and add in the void mouseDragged() {  it comes up as a token error.
Also when I try and get the mouse wheel to zoom it presents me with a token error as well. The code I used for the mousewheel was the following:
void mouseWheel(MouseEvent event) {
float e = event.getAmount();

Below is the current code I have written. I appreciate any help as i have been trying for days to figure this out.

````
Table table;
float wheelCount = 0;

//Pan & Zoom Varibles
float scale = 0.1;
float xPan;
float yPan;
boolean zoomIn = false;
boolean zoomOut = false;
boolean panUp = false;
boolean panDown = false ;
boolean panLeft = false;
boolean panRight = false;
float panSpeed = 5;
float zoomSpeed = 0.01;

float rotx = PI/4;
float roty = PI/4;

float x,y,z;
float w, h;

boolean census1991 = false;
boolean census2001 = false;
boolean census2011 = false;


void setup() {
  size(800, 600, P3D);
  
  table = loadTable ("Data.csv", "header");

  img = loadImage("uk-admin.jpg");
  
  textureMode(NORMAL);
  
   for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    int No = row.getInt("No");
    String City = row.getString("City");
    String Census1991 = row.getString("Census1991");
    String Census2001 = row.getString("Census2001");
    String Census2011 = row.getString("Census2011");
    
    println(No);
    println(City);
    println("Census 1991:", Census1991);
    println("Census 2001:", Census2001);
    println("Census 2011:", Census2011);
    println("Use the arrow keys to pan around the map");
    println("Press 'Z' to Zoom In and 'X' to Zoom Out");
    println("Left Click to Zoom In and Right Click to zoom");
    println("Use the Mouse Wheel to zoom in and out");
    println("Press '1' to view the Census from 1991");
    println("Press '2' to view the Census from 2001");
    println("Press '3' to view the Census from 2011");
    println("Press 'R' to remove Census data from the map");
    println("Scroll up in the console to view the exact population figures for each city in each Census");
   }
 }

void draw() {
  background(0);
  imageMode (CENTER);
  image(map, centerX, centerY, imgW, imgH);
  translate(width*0.5, height*0.5, 10);//translate the transformation point to the centre of the screen
  translate(-xPan, -yPan);
  rotateX(-PI/4);//apply a rotation about the x axis to tilt the plane we will be drawing to
  scale(scale);//you can apply a scaling factor here to suit the size of your img

 
  translate(-img.width/2, 0, -img.height/2);

  beginShape();
  texture(img);
  vertex(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);//texture uv coordinates are the last two numbers
  vertex(img.width, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  vertex(img.width, 0, img.height, 1, 1);
  vertex(0, 0, img.height, 0, 1);
  endShape();
  
  if (zoomIn) {
    scale +=zoomSpeed;
  }
  if (zoomOut) {
    scale -=zoomSpeed;
  }
  if (panUp) {
    yPan -=panSpeed;
  }
  if (panDown) {
    yPan +=panSpeed;
  }
  if (panLeft) {
    xPan -=panSpeed;
  }
  if (panRight) {
    xPan +=panSpeed;
  }
  
  if (census1991) {
    for (TableRow row : table.rows()) { 
    float lat = row.getFloat("Latitude");
    float lon = row.getFloat("Longitude");
    float Census1991 = row.getFloat("Census1991");
    float h = Census1991;
    float maxh = pow(10, 7);
    h = map(h, 0, maxh, 10, 100);
    x = lat;
    y = lon;
    z = 0;
    
    pushMatrix();
    translate(y, -z, x);
    fill(255,60,50);
    box(10, h, 10); 
    popMatrix();

      }
    } else if (census2001) {
    for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    float lat = row.getFloat("Latitude");
    float lon = row.getFloat("Longitude");
    float Census2001 = row.getFloat("Census2001");
    float h = Census2001;
    float maxh = pow(10, 7);
    h = map(h, 0, maxh, 10, 100);
    x = lat;
    y = lon;
    z = 0;
    
    pushMatrix();
    translate(y, -z, x);
    fill(100,60,50);
    box(10, h, 10);
    popMatrix();
      }
    } else if (census2011) {
    for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    float lat = row.getFloat("Latitude");
    float lon = row.getFloat("Longitude");
    float Census2011 = row.getFloat("Census2011");
    float h = Census2011;
    float maxh = pow(10, 7);
    h = map(h, 0, maxh, 10, 100);
    x = lat;
    y = lon;
    z = 0;
    
    pushMatrix();
    translate(y, -z, x);
    fill(205,78,80);
    box(10, h, 10);
    popMatrix();
      }
    }
  }
  // Pan & Zoom Controls

void keyPressed() {
 if (key == 'Z') {
   zoomIn= true;
   zoomOut= false;
   }
 if (key =='O') {
   zoomIn = false;
   zoomOut = true;
 }
 if (keyCode ==UP) {
   panUp = true;
   panDown= false;
 }
 if (keyCode == DOWN) {
   panDown = true;
   panUp= false;
 }
 if (keyCode == LEFT) {
   panLeft = true;
   panRight= false;
   }
 if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
   panRight = true;
   panLeft= false;
     }

if (key == '1') {
   census1991 = true;
   census2001 = false;
   census2011 = false;

 }
 
 if (key == '2') {
   census1991 = false;
   census2001 = true;
   census2011 = false;

 }
 
 if (key == '3') {
   census1991 = false;
   census2001 = false;
   census2011 = true;

 }
 
 if (key == 'r') {
    census1991 = false;
    census2001 = false;
    census2011 = false; 
  }
}
//Stops Pan & Zoom when keys are released.
 void keyReleased() {
  if(key == 'Z') {
    zoomIn = false;
  }
    if (key == 'O'){
    zoomOut = false;
  }
     if (keyCode == UP) {
    panUp = false;
  }
    if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    panDown = false;
  }
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    panLeft = false;
  }
   if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    panRight = false;
   }```
````

Comment: Please add more details, specifically about what you were trying to do, what you have tried so far, along with relevant code, if any. As it stands, the question is very vague to anyone else who reads it.

Comment: @Sumit thank you for that suggestion I have now updated my question

Comment: You might take a look at [PeasyCam](http://mrfeinberg.com/peasycam/). It should make that all much easier.